# Get value within TV’s html attribute in Modx

Tags: modx

I’m new to Modx so I don’t know if this is possible or not.

My TV, in this case `[[*myTV]]` outputs the following:

`<data value='www.mylink.com'>Description</data>`

Is there a way to only display the data value in the front-end? In this case I just want to display the url.

Comment: [[!myTV]] - this is a snippet call, could you please specify what code inside this snippet is?

Comment: I actually meant [[*myTV]], I've edited the question. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't store just the URL in the TV and have the surrounding tag in the template? Or a TV for the URL and another TV for the Description?

Comment: Good question @LIannotti, thanks for asking. it's multi-select TV so the user selects a value and that value should output a URL.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to keep the data (in this case the URL) and the html separate, and that might help your situation. If the TV only includes the URL itself, then it makes it much easier to deal with the output of the TV using output modifiers. As an example, if `[[*myTV]]` contains `www.mylink.com` for a particular resource and you want the original output in your question, you could do something like:

```
[[*myTV:default=`<data value='[[*myTV]]'>Description</data>`]]
```

You can also nest TVs within output modifiers, so if for example you had a corresponding `[[*description]]` TV that describes the URL in `[[*myTV]]`, you could use:

```
[[*myTV:default=`<data value='[[*myTV]]'>[[*description]]</data>`]]
```

**TL;DR... The short version:** Storing the entire output in the TV and extracting text from within that TV to output is much more difficult than storing individual components of that output in separate TVs and bringing them together for output when needed.

**The longer version:** In any situation where you're storing both data and HTML in a TV (which is not advisable in the vast majority of cases), you'll likely find duplication of your data across your project, and if by chance you decide to change the html at some point in the future, you then have to go into each and every TV field and change that HTML, which is the opposite effect from what a CMS is supposed to do - i.e. make ***C**ontent **M**anagement* easier!

If you do happen to find a use case for storing TVs along with their HTML formatting, that is a job best left for MODX Chunks, where you can code the implementation of your TVs within HTML in one spot within MODX and instead of duplicating that code everywhere, you reference the chunk like so: `[[$chunk]]`.